# How can I know if the image is in RGB or BGR format?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, rgb, bgr

Is there any way to know in advance if an image used as an input to a system is in RGB or BGR format?

I am using OpenCV with java API and I would like to convert an input image into grayscale or L*a*b* color space, but in OpenCV you have to specify first whether the image you want to convert is in RGB or BGR.

The type of the image I am using is either `.jpg` or `.png`.

Comment: Depends on the type of image you are using... Which image type are you using ?

Comment: @CoderNeji please see the update section above

Comment: I think @Jean-BaptisteYunès gave you the right answer process the image as buffered image first and then you can set flags accordingly for RGB or BGR format

Comment: If you load image with OpenCV functions it will be BGR, as far as i know there's still no function to check the color space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your image is a `BufferedImage` then you can ask for his type with `getType()`, and test against the several constants (see: [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getType())).

Answer (score 27):

If you are reading in the image file, or you have access to the code that reads in the file, know it is:

- [BGR](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imread) order if you used `cv2.imread()`
- [RGB](https://matplotlib.org/api/image_api.html#matplotlib.image.imread) order if you used `mpimg.imread()` (assuming `import matplotlib.image as mpimg`)

If you don't know how the file was opened, the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30802605/5411817) `BufferedImage` is great for Java.
I would like to find a way to do the same in Python!

Comment: It's important to note that with matplotlib,  RGB is specifically for JPG images.  PNG images will load as BGRA.

Answer (score 9):

When you use opencv (imread, VideoCapture), the images are loaded in the BGR color space.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but you might add some supporting documentation: http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/highgui/Highgui.html#imread(java.lang.String) "Note: In the case of color images, the decoded images will have the channels stored in B G R order."

Comment: In the future I will try to do it, thanks for advicing